# VBA If Then stament returning error in For Each loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am trying to write a VBA code that inspects each element in a specified column of a named range using an If Then statement nested in a For Each loop. This code is trying to test out a subroutine for a larger project.

My named range is "Nregion"

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim singlecell As Range
Dim listofcells As Range

Set listofcells = Range("Nregion").Columns(2)

For Each singlecell In listofcells
If singlecell.Value > 4 Then singlecell.Value = "Big"
Next

End Sub
```

The named region is populated with random numbers. When I run the macro I get a **Run time error 13: Type mismatch**. When I select debug, it highlights the half of the If Then statement prior to "then".

```
If singlecell.Value > 4 Then
```

This routine works fine when I use the a fixed range or the entire named range as the target of the For Each loop, but returns an error when I try to inspect only a single column of my named range. Does anyone know why this is and how to work around it?

Comment: do you have text or errors in the cells you are iterating?

Comment: Another question you might want to add to that is how to debug it..  Have you tried without the for loop? e.g. just testing the value of the first element?

Comment: Also, I don't know VBA, but if singlecell is a range, would you even say `singlecell.Value` And regardless, Really you should try testing things without a for loop. That's basic troubleshooting

Comment: @barlop `.Value` is the actual default for a range.  It can be omitted but personally see it better programming to declare it.

Comment: @ScottCraner ".Value is the actual default for a range." OK..that's fine.  And I wasn't suggeting omitting it.

Comment: I have done some debugging. I tried it without the .columns(2) on the range assignment for listofcells. worked fine. so it isn't likely bad data It works fine when used on the entire named range. there is some issue with the column selection but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: @nn6580 Always specify properties and datatypes. Don't rely on defaults. *When I select debug, it* Open Locals window and look carefully on all datatypes, open Watch window and do the same with used expressions.

Comment: @ScottCraner *`.Value` is the actual default for a range.* That's true... but can you provide a criteria which ALWAYS allows to define does the object or its default will be used in each particular case?

Comment: `Set listofcells = Range("Nregion").Columns(2).CELLS`

Comment: @jeeped, holy cow, that worked. thanks a million. I am a bit new to VBA, do you have any explanation as to why that worked? thanks again.

Comment: (Assuming that what I heard re VBA is correct), How did you manage to type a dot and then refer to a property or function that doesn't exist, when VBA has a(presumably automatic), autosuggest feature that'd list all the functions for you after you hit dot. Did you just copy paste? The most basic troubleshooting is you type it out yourself, which you should have done anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by setting *listofcells* to the `Cells` in `Columns(2)`. Yes, they are both range objects but Columns and Columns.Cells have different properties.

```
Set listofcells = Range("Nregion").Columns(2).CELLS
```

The easiest way to explain it is that your original was saying `For each column in columns` and `column` doesn't have `column.value` as a property. You needed `For each cells in columns.cells` 'cause `cells.value` is a legal property when `cells` is a single cell. This mistake is typically made on `Rows` but the same principle covers `Columns`.

Comment: does VBA have autocompletion that'd 'prevent' somebody writing dot followed by a property or function that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes and no. VBA has an autocomplete but only provides suggestions; it doesn’t stop you from typing in the wrong one. Truth be told, that would be a neat trick since Range.Value is only valid when Range is a single cell

Comment: Yes I mean suggestions obviously. An IDE shouldn't force a programmer. None do. A programmer is meant to use their intelligence